# Why if A it's hermitian and positive-definite matrix, it's possible to factorize it with a lower–upper (LU) decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Why if A it's hermitian and  positive-definite matrix, it's possible to factorize it with a  lower–upper (LU) decomposition?

If this two hipothesis are true, then all the principal minors of the matrix are invertible.

Comment: To the OP. On this website, usage is, if one is satisfied with an answer, then one upvotes it and (or) one gives the green ticket or, if one is not satisfied, then one writes why

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a Hermitian matrix. Then $A>0$ iff its principal minors have a $>0 $ determinant.